# Accessing Session variable in Webform and looping

Tags: asp.net, session, web, foreach, session-variables

I have stored a list of type advertisements (Object i created) in a session. I want to access the session in a foreach loop in a webform and display the records in a table.

But i am getting compilation error:

"Error  4   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    c:\Users\Troller\Desktop\B.W.A. Project\B.W.A. Project New\AutoMobileWebsite\View_Advertisement.aspx    87  17  AutoMobileWebsite"

Below is my code for accessing the list in session and looping to get the data

```
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Advertisement Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <%foreach (Business_Layer.Advertisement iter in Session["ViewAds"]) ; %>
          <td>iter.getTopic()</td>
          </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to fix this error.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try 'foreach (Business_Layer.Advertisement iter in (Session["ViewAds"] as IEnumerable<Business_Layer.Advertisement >))' if have a typed list

Comment: @Fabio Thanks, it fixed the error but i cant access the method get topic by using the iter. Do you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: Assume your object is serializable?

Comment: Try like this <%iter.getTopic(); %>

Comment: @MartinSmellworse how do i make it serializable ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad i tried doesn't work

Comment: remove semicolon from end of foreach loop and then try the same syntax.